# How important is a small Docker image when running?

Tags: docker

There are a number of really tiny Linux Docker images that weigh in around 4-5M and the "full" distros that start around 100M and climb to twice that.

Setting aside storage space and download time from a repo, are there runtime considerations to small vs large images? For example if I have a compiled Go program, one running on Busybox and the other on Ubuntu, and I run say 10 of them on a machine, in what ways (if any) does it matter than one image is tiny and the other pretty heavy?  Does one consume more runtime resources than the other?

Answer (score 1):

I never saw any **real** difference in consuming other resources than storage and RAM if the image is bigger, however, as Docker containers should be single process why having the big overhead of unused clutter in your containers?

When trimming things down to small containers, there some advantages you may consider:

- Faster transfer when deploying (esp. important if you wan't to do rolling upgrades)
- Costs: The most time I used big containers, I ran exactly into storage issues on small VMs
- Distributed File Systems: When using some File Storage like GlusterFS or other attached storage, big containers slow down, when bootet and updated heavily
- massive overhead of data: if you have 500 MB clutter, you'll have it on your dev-machine, your CI/CD-Server, your registry AND every node of your production servers. This CAN matter depending on your use case.

I would say: If you just use a handful containers internally then the size is less important, if ever, than using hundrets of containers in production.

Comment: I am sometimes running more than one process in a container (supporting processes under supervision).  I guess what I'm asking is if I have 1G image and a 5M image holding the same compiled Go script, will Docker consume 1G/5M of RAM when I fire up the image, or in either case just enough to run the Go program?  I may want 100 of these running in prod so I want to get an idea of whether the number of boxes I need to run these is dependent on my code or the size of the Docker images.